# Vtk Heatmap: Scientific visualization of Radar data: Updating the vtkFloatArray for a vtkPlaneSource

Tags: c++, vtk

Being a beginnger with vtk it's a bit hard to know *where* to start. What I'm trying to do is a `radar view` using data that's send to me every time a sensor is full (and that represents a single row). My initial idea was to use a grid and map the values that I get as Z's, filling the grid a column at a time.

Each time the sensors is filled, I call an update function that should update the Scalars of the vtkPlaneData

A few things to consider:

- I don't know if I'm using the best structures for the problem, vtk has too many structures and I'm just learning.
- I know c++ but I'm not good with 3d software (yet).

```
void Window::handleData(const std::vector<float> data)
{
    vtkFloatArray* currentCellData = dynamic_cast<vtkFloatArray*>(
         m_planeSource->GetOutput()->GetCellData()->GetScalars());

    vtkFloatArray* cellData = vtkFloatArray::New();
    cellData->SetNumberOfComponents(1);
    cellData->SetNumberOfValues(2000 * 2000);

    // Move elements one row above;
    for (vtkIdType i = 0, end = 200 * 200 - 200; i < end; i++) {
        cellData->SetValue(i + 200, currentCellData->GetValue(i));
    }

    // Add the new row.
    for (vtkIdType i = 0, end = 200; i < end; i++)
    {
        cellData->SetValue(i, data[(int)i]);
    }

    // update the cells
    planeSource->GetOutput()->GetCellData()->SetScalars(cellData);

    // update the window
    renderWindow->GetInteractor()->Render();
 }
```

I know that the code smells fishy, I'm not reusing the data vector and I'm doing a monstruosity iterating thru all the elements every time to append the last row.

When I reused the same cellData the view did not refresh the heatmap.

So, my questions:

- How can I "shift left" a row in the `vtkFloatArray`? (being it N * M elements, I want to << M; to move all elements one row up and leave the last row free)
- How can I append a row directly without having to iterate thru all the items (something like `cellData.insertAt(pos, array.data(), array.size())`)

  - How can I reutilize the current `CellData()->Scalars()` from the PlaneSource to not need to allocate / deallocate memory every step?